# How to set stripe webhooks?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I have tried to set up a stripe webhook locally and in the stripe dashboard.
Locally the webhook worked fine, but when I specified an url in the dashboard the server gave me 404 error code. How do you fix this?

Comment: One thing, I am using live api key on the server instead of a test could this be the issue?

Comment: The community is going to need more information in order to provide assistance. When working with webhook events, you create and control the endpoint that those events are sent to. So in the scenario you're describing, it is your server that is returning the 404 status. What troubleshooting/investigating have you done so far regarding your endpoint?